# FailureResponse on otherwise successful OpenID login: Server denied check_authentication

Tags: openid, python-openid

I'm testing OpenID authentication using python-openid on webpy's development web server.  Through Yahoo! and myOpenID, I keep getting a failure response with the message **Server denied check_authentication**.  The strange part is, I also receive the correct `openid.identity`.

The same type of authentication works fine with Google (@ https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud...).  On one hand, that gives me confidence that I'm doing something right, but on the other hand, the inconsistency confuses me.

`return_to` & `trust_root` are both localhost:8080, which may have something to do with it.

Here's the code I use to send the user to Yahoo! to authenticate:

```
  def POST(self):
    post_data = web.input()
    if post_data.has_key('openid_identifier'):
      openid_identifier = post_data.get('openid_identifier')
      c = Consumer(session, openid.store.memstore.MemoryStore())
      auth = c.begin(openid_identifier)
      auth_url = auth.redirectURL('http://localhost:8080', return_to='http://localhost:8080/authenticate')
      raise web.seeother(auth_url)
    return post_data
```

`auth_url` in this case is set to (formatted for easy reading):

```
https://open.login.yahooapis.com/openid/op/auth?
openid.assoc_handle=cYSO3wJSjQa3ewmRpaQz3YodzqjosP1ta.4TVzumqlLpAFM7oWci6K9bMKG4uuqZ.5m.fY7Wp8BWfQ1eR_soHWpJ6gCsKtxi_7Bqi22T5RUcMIuQBVjpGFSjc_kRY2k-&
openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&
openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&
openid.mode=checkid_setup&
openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080&
openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fauthenticate%3Fjanrain_nonce%3D2010-10-08T02%253A56%253A04ZrxAI
```

Here's what the handler looks like at the return URL:

```
  def GET(self):
    data = web.input()
    c = Consumer(session, openid.store.memstore.MemoryStore())
    result = c.complete(dict(data), current_url='http://localhost:8080/authenticate')
    if result.status == SUCCESS:
      openid_identity = data.get('openid.identity')
      ...
    render = web.template.render('templates/', base='layout')
    return render.error(...)
```

`result` gets set to `<openid.consumer.consumer.FailureResponse id=None message='Server denied check_authentication'>`, and `data` (the query parameters on the return) are set like this:

```
<Storage {'openid.op_endpoint': u'https://open.login.yahooapis.com/openid/op/auth', 
'openid.sig': u'yCHffpHs2Whtw9p1gPzC+ToQJ0k=', 
'openid.ns': u'http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0', 
'janrain_nonce': u'2010-10-08T02:56:04ZrxAIWh', 
'openid.return_to': u'http://localhost:8080/authenticate?janrain_nonce=2010-10-08T02%3A56%3A04ZrxAIWh', 
'openid.pape.auth_level.nist': u'0', 
'openid.claimed_id': u'https://me.yahoo.com/a/d3eEQZAWydfmtDwaGB2vBEVU4vIMLsez#1ac56', 
'openid.mode': u'id_res', 
'openid.realm': u'http://localhost:8080', 
'openid.response_nonce': u'2010-10-08T02:55:52ZRLNmEd7aWiaGWjHfhqEQs2Fxj3.nXdwciA--', 
'openid.signed': u'assoc_handle,claimed_id,identity,mode,ns,op_endpoint,response_nonce,return_to,signed,pape.auth_level.nist', 
'openid.identity': u'https://me.yahoo.com/a/d3eEQZAWydfmtDwaGB2vBEVU4vIMLsez', 
'openid.assoc_handle': u'cYSO3wJSjQa3ewmRpaQz3YodzqjosP1ta.4TVzumqlLpAFM7oWci6K9bMKG4uuqZ.5m.fY7Wp8BWfQ1eR_soHWpJ6gCsKtxi_7Bqi22T5RUcMIuQBVjpGFSjc_kRY2k-'}>
```

That sure doesn't look like a failure response to me.  Notice that `openid.identity` is set.  And yes, that is my OpenID identity on Yahoo!.

I'm not sure where to take this from here.  Any words of advice?

Comment: If the server has refused check_authentication, or it has returned false, you should assume that the user did not authenticate. check_authentication is used to verify that the data you've got comes from the OP, and not from any other source. I don't know however, what could cause it to happen in this case.

Comment: In this case I have an association handle, so `check_authentication` shouldn't even be attempted.  I must using the python-openid API incorrectly, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Have you looked at `django-openid-auth` and `django-openid-consumer`? The contain debugged examples on how to handle OpenID requests.

Comment: I haven't, but I'll take a look.  Thanks for the advice.  I'm not using Django, but I was following the Django example distributed with python-openid.  I decided to use python-openid since it was the one referenced from http://www.openenabled.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The consumer needs a data store to maintain state between discovery and authentication.  The store I was using, `openid.store.memstore.MemoryStore()`, did not actually maintain state between requests.  It only maintains state within a process -- as you would expect from "memory" (duh).  The bit that had to change is the creation of the consumer in both the GET and POST handlers.

Here's the wrong way to create the consumer:

```
# BAD: MemoryStore() has a short memory -- within the process only
c = Consumer(session, openid.store.memstore.MemoryStore())
```

And here's the right way to create the consumer:

```
# GOOD: MySQL has a long memory -- across processes
db = web.database(dbn='mysql', db='somedb', user='someuser', pw='')
conn = db._db_cursor().connection
cstore = sqlstore.MySQLStore(conn, 'openid_associations', 'openid_nonces')
c = Consumer(session, cstore)
```

I suppose it helps to remember your assoc handles and nonces.  I must have been stuck here for 10 hours, so I hope this helps the next guy (or gal) avoid doing the same.

This'll be the first bounty I ever won -- my own.  Woot!

Parting note: This assumes you have set up the OpenID tables in your database, which should look like this in MySQL:

```
create table openid_nonces (
  server_url blob not null,
  timestamp integer not null,
  salt char(40) not null,
  primary key (server_url(255), timestamp, salt)
) engine=InnoDB;

create table openid_associations (
  server_url blob not null,
  handle varchar(255) not null,
  secret blob not null,
  issued integer not null,
  lifetime integer not null,
  assoc_type varchar(64) not null,
  primary key (server_url(255), handle)
) engine=InnoDB;
```

Check the openid.store.sqlstore section of [the documentation](http://openidenabled.com/files/python-openid/docs/1.2.0/) for related SQL statements for your specific store.